Rename and reset a file creating a ZIP in Azure Data Factory
I'm banging my head trying to do the following (I don't even know if it's possible): create a ZIP, based on a list of files (using "List of Files" option) and, at the same time, rename a file and store it in a different folder, using Azure Data Factory.
I have multiple files stored in a Blob Storage, with the format Guid/Guid, where the 1st and 2nd guid represent keys in a Table Storage (PartitionKey + RowKey).
Basically, I need to provide a list of files do ADF, in some way (that's the question) in the TXT file pass the original file name and the destination of the file inside the ZIP file!
I known that using, for example, an Azure Function, I can accomplish that, but I want to know if there's a more straightfoward or simple way, without using any other Azure resource (like Functions or Notebooks).
My knowledge of ADF is limited, but until know I cannot find a way to do it using the "List of Files" option.

There is no default option to rename a file in ADF. So, first you need to create a new file with the new name in the same location (or different location as per your requirement) using copy activity. Then use delete activity to delete the original file. In this way a file with the new name will be created.
To create a zip file from the list of file paths, first you need to a text file which contains the required file paths.
You can go through this SO answer to generate the required text file. You can filter out the required file paths using filter transformation in between the dataflow.
After generating the file from dataflow, the file will contain the file paths like below for sample.
folder1/file1.json
folder1/subfolder1/file2.json
DS_STORAGE_2024.csv
folder2/file3.json


This is a sample folder structure in container 30thcon.
30thcon
    folder1
        subfolder1
            file2.json
        file1.json
        hi.csv
    folder2
        file3.json
        file4.json
    DS_STORAGE_2024.csv

From the above container, the file from the text file will be created as a zip file.
Take a binary source dataset with file path till the container. Leave the compression type as it is in this.

Give this dataset to copy activity source and give the text file path.

For target also, create another binary dataset and give a target filename like target.zip. Give the ZipDeflate (.zip) as compression type.

Debug the copy activity and the zip file will be created in the target. You can see it contains the file paths from the text file.


Thanks for the answer @Rakesh Govindula!
I can't delete the original file, it needs to exist to be used in my application, but now I see that I need to copy the file to a new folder, already with the structure that I need and then create a ZIP file.
Is it possible to add files to that ZIP file? Or the moment the ZIP is created by ADF the stream is closed and does not accept any updates?

AFAIK, Zip file cannot accept updates once its created. You cannot add files to the created zip file. First you need to copy the required file to required location and add that file's path to the text file. It means after arranging all the file paths, then only you need to create the zip file.
